# Saving Model State and Load in Google Colab

Tags: python, tensorflow, pytorch

I have 500 epochs in total to train . But it is taking 8 minutes per epoch to be completed in google colab. Can any one help me how can I save my Model state after a Particular number of epoch  completion and start the training again from where I left in google Colab ??

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please consider posting the relevant code.

Comment: You can mount your Google Drive on colab and save/load the model_dict directly into your drive after every `n` epochs. Here's an [example](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1CN7JxLA_Qk1Clc4CM75rSAqIlUKIF8xZ)

Comment: Here is the general example of how can you save and load checkpoint in pytorch. - https://pytorch.org/tutorials/recipes/recipes/saving_and_loading_a_general_checkpoint.html

Comment: from imageai.Detection.Custom import DetectionModelTrainer

trainer = DetectionModelTrainer()
trainer.setModelTypeAsYOLOv3()
trainer.setDataDirectory(data_directory="/content/drive/My Drive/Dataset")
trainer.setTrainConfig(object_names_array=["object1","object 2"], batch_size=4, num_experiments=421)
trainer.trainModel()

Comment: here is my code

Answer (score 2):

If you want to save the model to google drive after certain number of epochs in pytorch you can do so by using

first mount google drive

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/gdrive')
```

Then the run the cell in colab and authenticate. Now google drive should be mounted.
Now set the path to be

`PATH = F"/content/gdrive/My Drive/{Model name}/{model_save_name}"`

you can the save the model

```
    if(epoch%(number_epoch_to_save)==0):
        torch.save(model.state_dict(), PATH)
```

example documentation can be found here at https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/saving_loading_models.html

Answer (score 1):

If you are using tensorflow then, you can use keras's `ModelCheckpoint` callback to do that. Mount your google drive to save the model.

```
pip install -q pyyaml h5py  # Required to save models in HDF5 format

filepath = '/content/drive/'
checkpoint_callback = tf.keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(filepath= filepath, 
                                                         save_weights_only=True, save_best_only=True)

model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=500, callbacks= [checkpoint_callback])
```

Model weights are saved at the end of every epoch, if it's the best seen so far.
You can load the model weights later:

```
model.load_weights(checkpoint_filepath)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! When I am doing `model.load_weights('./path/to/the/model_file.h5')` within the colab session in which I created the model everything works fine. But when I restart the colab notebook (and all variables are erased) I can no longer find this file. Does it really get deleted with the end of the session or can I find it somehow? Thanks